# Lower bound of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ where
$$ x_n = \left[ 1 - \left(\frac {n}{n+1} \right)^k \right]$$
with $k\ge 2$ and $n\ge N_0 \ge 1$. 
I want to find an lower bound such as
$$ \left[ 1 - \left(\frac {n}{n+1} \right)^k \right] \ge k\frac{N_0}{N_0+1}f(n,k)$$
where $f(n,k)$ is an expression of $n$ and $k$. 
Is it possible for the lower bound, thanks for your answers or suggestions.

Comment: $\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
x_n=\frac{(n+1)^k-n^k}{(n+1)^k}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{i}n^i\ge k\,\frac{n^{k-1}}{(n+1)^k}\ge k\,\frac{N_0}{N_0+1}\,\frac{n^{k-1}}{(n+1)^k}.
$$
I added the fraction involving $N_0$ to get an inequality in the form you asked. You can get
$$
x_n\ge\Bigl(\frac{N_0}{N_0+1}\Bigr)^k\frac{k}{n},\quad n\ge N_0,
$$
which is not exactly what you asked for.